# Cancel first dialog from an inner dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created a dialog which contains a list view. The onclicklistener for the list view dialog then loads a new, inner dialog asking the user to confirm their choice.

Once this is done i want to close both the outer and inner dialog boxes. I am able to close the inner one no problem but am struggling to figure out a way to close the outer dialog which contains a list view from the inner.

An extract of my code is below:

```
// Display list of sites
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            this);
                    builder.setTitle("Sites Near Me");

                    ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
                    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < possibleLocaitons.size(); i++) {
                        String currentLocation = possibleLocaitons.get(i)
                                .getName();
                        stringArrayList.add(currentLocation);
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1, stringArrayList);
                    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);

                    // List click listener
                    modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int pos, long id) {

                            String site = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
                                    .toString();

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                    LocationActivity.this);

                            // set title
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("");

                            // set dialog message
                            alertDialogBuilder
                                    .setMessage("Check in at " + site + "?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton(
                                            "Yes",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                                    // Update the database
                                                    UserFunctions us = new UserFunctions();
                                                    us.updateLocation(
                                                            "fish", "888");
                                                    dialog.cancel();


                                                }
                                            })
                                    .setNegativeButton(
                                            "Cancel",
                                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(
                                                        DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int id) {
                                                    dialog.cancel();
                                                }
                                            });

                            // create alert dialog
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder
                                    .create();

                            // show it
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }

                    });

                    builder.setView(modeList);
                    final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

                    dialog.show();

                }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57441159/Screenshot_2012-10-21-10-13-21.png

When "yes" is clicked i want to cancel both the "sites near me" and "check in at" dialogs, returning to the map activity in the background. Currently it only cancels "check in at" then returns to "sites near me". I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access this piece of code from alertDialogBuilder's anonymous onClick() since it is forward referenced

```
 final Dialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.show();
```

Move it under `builder.setTitle("Sites Near Me");`. The proceed to dismiss the dialog from a UI thread using activity.runOnUiThread().

Comment: Thanks that worked. I declared the first dialog at the start of the class then just cancelled it in the onclicklistener. Is this bad practice opposed to using a thread? Thanks again

Comment: hmmm... I just realized you are dismissing the dialog from the onClickListener and not a background thread. That should be fine. The thumb rule is to make UI changes on UI threads.